# Kubernetes: Can't Resolve Hostnames from within pods

Tags: kubernetes, dns

new to Kubernetes, but have used K3s a little in the past. Just setup a K8s cluster. None of my pods can do DNS lookups, even to google, or to an internal domain.

I init'd with: `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`. Metal-LB is installed (10.7.7.10-10.7.7.254) and the nodes and master are running with IPs 10.7.50.X/16 and 10.7.60.X/16 respectively. Flannel is setup with the default Kube-Flannel: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

So far it's just 1 master with 2 nodes.

Versions:

```
$ kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:44:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:45:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:39:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

$ kubelet --version
Kubernetes v1.22.1
```

Troubleshooting commands:

```
$ kubectl describe service kube-dns -n kube-system
Name:              kube-dns
Namespace:         kube-system
Labels:            k8s-app=kube-dns
                   kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true
                   kubernetes.io/name=CoreDNS
Annotations:       prometheus.io/port: 9153
                   prometheus.io/scrape: true
Selector:          k8s-app=kube-dns
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.96.0.10
IPs:               10.96.0.10
Port:              dns  53/UDP
TargetPort:        53/UDP
Endpoints:         10.244.1.20:53,10.244.2.28:53
Port:              dns-tcp  53/TCP
TargetPort:        53/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.1.20:53,10.244.2.28:53
Port:              metrics  9153/TCP
TargetPort:        9153/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.1.20:9153,10.244.2.28:9153
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE     IP            NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
coredns-84f8874d6d-jgvwk          1/1     Running   1 (115m ago)   21h     10.244.1.20   k-w-001   <none>           <none>
coredns-84f8874d6d-qh2f4          1/1     Running   1 (115m ago)   21h     10.244.2.28   k-w-002   <none>           <none>
etcd-k-m-001                      1/1     Running   12 (15m ago)   2d22h   10.7.50.11    k-m-001   <none>           <none>
kube-apiserver-k-m-001            1/1     Running   11 (15m ago)   2d22h   10.7.50.11    k-m-001   <none>           <none>
kube-controller-manager-k-m-001   1/1     Running   12 (15m ago)   2d22h   10.7.50.11    k-m-001   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-286dc             1/1     Running   10 (15m ago)   2d22h   10.7.50.11    k-m-001   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-rbmhx             1/1     Running   6 (114m ago)   2d21h   10.7.60.11    k-w-001   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-vjl7l             1/1     Running   4 (115m ago)   2d21h   10.7.60.12    k-w-002   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-948z8                  1/1     Running   8 (15m ago)    2d22h   10.7.50.11    k-m-001   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-l7h64                  1/1     Running   4 (115m ago)   2d21h   10.7.60.12    k-w-002   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-pqmsr                  1/1     Running   4 (115m ago)   2d21h   10.7.60.11    k-w-001   <none>           <none>
kube-scheduler-k-m-001            1/1     Running   12 (15m ago)   2d22h   10.7.50.11    k-m-001   <none>           <none>
metrics-server-6dfddc5fb8-47mnb   0/1     Running   3 (115m ago)   2d20h   10.244.1.21   k-w-001   <none>           <none>
```

```
$ kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system coredns-84f8874d6d-jgvwk
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = db32ca3650231d74073ff4cf814959a7
CoreDNS-1.8.4
linux/amd64, go1.16.4, 053c4d5

$ kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system coredns-84f8874d6d-qh2f4
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = db32ca3650231d74073ff4cf814959a7
CoreDNS-1.8.4
linux/amd64, go1.16.4, 053c4d5
```

These were ran seconds apart:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

*** Can't find kubernetes.default: No answer

*** Can't find kubernetes.default: No answer

$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
```

Here are some more tests:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1

$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.251.33.78

*** Can't find google.com: No answer

$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=116 time=6.437 ms

$ kubectl exec busybox -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5

$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default  10.96.0.10
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

*** Can't find kubernetes.default: No answer

*** Can't find kubernetes.default: No answer

$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default 10.96.0.10
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
```

I also noticed that the kube-dns service has the app selector set to `k8s-app=kube-dns` and coredns has the label `k8s-app=kube-dns`, is this correct?

The pods running in the kube-system namespace seem to have 2 different IP ranges. One is using the Node's IP, and the other is using Flannels.

I'm not sure what's happening here, being new to Kubernetes, but it appears like the DNS pods or service are not working at all.

Edit:

Further info:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Comment: Did you check your server itself? It's a firewall running?

Comment: @Manuel How do I check this? I configured no firewall, it should just be standard Ubuntu iptables rules, plus what ever Docker and Kubernetes have added.

Comment: [check firewall](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ufw-ubuntu-firewall/ubuntu-check-firewall-status-ufw/). Please also paste your dns-pod logs.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak `sudo ufw status` outputs `Status: inactive`

Comment: Are you able to call any endpoint from the machines itself (not kubernetes yet)? curl google.com

Comment: @Manuel Yup, that works fine. I reinstalled the cluster and the exact same thing is happening. I think Metal-LB is messing with coredns or kube proxy, which is strange because it worked fine with K3s.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was actually Flannel. DNS queries worked fine until the nodes were restarted, and then all pod queries failed until the Flannel pods were restarted.

Man this was a rabbit hole.

See: https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/issues/1321